# Almacenar una fecha en Firestore desde c#

Tags: c#, firebase, datetime, google-cloud-firestore, datetimepicker

les cuento.
Estoy haciendo una pequeña aplicación en c# conectada a firebase, especificamente a firestore. El problema es que cuando intento enviar una fecha seleccionada desde el date time picker, los datos no se agregar, si omito la fecha si lo hacen. Es decir que el único problema es la fecha.

para agregar los datos lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
Public void agregarEstudiante(String codigo, String nombres, String apellidos,
            int telefono, DateTime fechaNacimiento)
        {


            DocumentReference doc = db.Collection("Estudiante").Document(codigo);
            Dictionary<string, object> data1 = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                {"codigo",  codigo },
                {"nombres",  nombres },
                {"apellidos", apellidos },
                {"telefono",  telefono },
                {"Fecha Nacimiento", fechaNacimiento },
                

            };
            doc.SetAsync(data1);
        }
```

y pues en el boton de agregar obtengo los valores de mis TextBox y ya, para la fecha lo estaba haciendo de las siguientes dos formas:

```
DateTime fecha = dateTimeFecha.Value;
```

y

```
String strFecha = dateTimeFecha.Value.ToShortDateString();
DateTime fecha = DateTime.Parse(strFecha);
```

Pero ninguna de las dos me sirve, alguno sabe que podría estar haciendo mal, o de que manera puedo solucionar esto? Gracias,

Comment: Hola, porque dices que no te sirve si la propiedad value retorna un DateTime, revisa cual es el tipo de datos fecha de tu gestor de base de datos, el formato de fecha en que se guarda una fecha en tu gestor

Comment: Hola,Pues en firestore se guardan como un timestamp

Comment: ahi esta la cosa, c# lo trata como DateTime y tu gestor como timestamp, debes convertir al tipo de datos que mas te convenga, o desde c# trabajas como timestamp, o quiza tu gestor tiene el tipo de dato DateTime

Comment: pero y como haria eso? por que c# no maneja timestamp y firestore tampoco DateTime, hay alguna forma de hacer esa conversión?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219797/how-to-get-correct-timestamp-in-c-sharp/21219819, entra aqui, ahi te explican, me parece que lo que buscas esta a partir de la segunda respuesta

Comment: cuál SDK de firestore estás usando? Ahí debe haber una clase `Timestamp` con un constructor que reciba un número entero. Ese es el que debes usar pasandole tu fecha convertida a tiempo a unix.

Comment: Tienes razon, si esta Timestamp, y tiene este metodo para convertir un DateTime en Timestamp, imestamp.FromDateTime(fecha). Sin embargo, me sale este error. Conversion from DateTime to Timestamp requires the DateTime kind to be Utc.

Comment: prueba esto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40272749/how-to-convert-datetime-of-type-datetimekind-unspecified-to-datetime-kind-utc-in

Answer (score 0):

Espero hayas resuelto, sino para quien lo requiera. La fecha a almacenar tiene que ser en formato UTC :

```
    {"Fecha Nacimiento", fechaNacimiento.ToUniversalTime()}
```

Y para obtenerlo se tiene que convertir nuevamente al formato local

```
    fechaNacimiento.ToLocalTime();
```

Saludos!

Comment: Cuidado! Convertir la fecha de nacimiento a la zona horaria del cliente, puede generar que la fecha de nacimiento "cambie". Las fechas (nacimiento) suelen ser YYYY-MM-DD, sin el tiempo, por lo tanto es importante mostrar el día en el que nació más allá de la zona horaria que se esté utilizando.